# Javascript connection to WebSocket on localhost and google chrome: connection failed (working on postman)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket

I'm trying to connect to `ws://localhost:8080` inside my React application.
The web browser I'm using is Google Chrome.

I can connect to the websocket in Postman, but on google chrome I'm getting this error:
`WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/tables' failed:`.

Source code of the application is:

```
    const ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/tables');

    ws.onmessage = function message(data: any) {
        console.log('received: %s', data);
    };
```

What am I getting wrong?